# Fact Check: Is any maximum clique also a maximal one?

Tags: graph-theory, np-complete

According to Wikipedia:

A maximal clique is a clique that is not included in a larger clique.

and

A maximum clique is a clique that includes the largest possible number of vertices.

Comment: Definitions are your friends.  The body of the Question includes both relevant definitions, but does not include the question posed in the title.  The extra space afforded by the Question's body allows you to clarify the problem statement, and you should avoid posting the problem statement only in the title.  Providing it in the body may seem redundant, but it helps to clarify for Readers exactly what the difficulty is and hence what help is needed.

Comment: Alright, thanks for your advice. I will consider this next time, it's just that the wiki page doesn't mention the fact and neither does any of the posts I checked here that deal with the "Maximum vs. Maximal Clique" topic, so I wanted to clear my doubts before using the fact in a homework problem (we were never introduced to maximal cliques).

Comment: It might be desirable to have examples that show a maximal clique need not be a maximum clique.  A little thought would I'm sure suggest such an example, and including it in your Question would have been the kind of context I'm suggesting.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If it has the largest possible number of vertices, a larger clique can't exist, so ...